# how can i make this function?(same result check)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making MBTI app with ReactJS
But I have some problem now

When I click button i got some string ex 'E or I'
and then When it finished I got String value ex'EEINNSTTFPPJ'
so I want to change this value to 'ENTP'

How Can I make it ? 1.state

```
const TOTAL_SLIDES = 12
const [score, setScore] = useState(0)
const [type, setType] = useState([])
const [num, setNum] = useState(0)
const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(1)
const slideRef = createRef(null)
const history = useHistory()
const [mbti, setMbti] = useState('')
```

2.funtion

```
   const nextSlideFir = () => {
            setNum(num + 1)
            setType(questions[num].answers[0].type)
            setMbti(mbti + type)
            setCurrentSlide(currentSlide + 1)
            slideRef.current.style.transform += 'translateX(-100vw)'
        
        }
        const nextSlideSec = () => {
            setNum(num + 1)
            setType(questions[num].answers[1].type)
            setMbti(mbti + type)
            setCurrentSlide(currentSlide + 1)
            slideRef.current.style.transform += 'translateX(-100vw)'
            
        }
    
//I Don't know how to get same duplicate values
        const mbitChecker = string => {
    const words = [string]
    return words.filter((item, index) => words.indexOf(item) !== index)
}
        useEffect(() => {
            currentSlide > TOTAL_SLIDES &&
                mbitChecker(mbti) &&
                history.push(`/result/${mbti}`)
        })

)
```

Comment: You might have to show how you set mbti. Is it state?

Comment: Yes I'm using useState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to, but you have better to have useEffect's dependency array

```js
const extractDuplicates = (text) => {
  // extractDuplicates('EEINNSTTFPPJ') -> "ENTP"
  const ans = []
  for (t of text) {
    if (text.indexOf(t) !== text.lastIndexOf(t)) {
      if (ans.indexOf(t) < 0) {
        ans.push(t)
      }
    }
  }
  return ans.join('')
}
```

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        currentSlide > TOTAL_SLIDES && history.push(`/result/${mbti}`)
        console.log(`${mbti}`)
        mbitChecker()
    }, [mbti])
```

Comment: Thanks How can I get Duplicate values ?                                                     
 const mbitChecker = string => {
  const words = [string]
  const result = words.filter((word, index) => word.indexOf(word !== index))
  return console.log(result)
 }

Comment: Thank you so much dude ! I solved it ! Have a Good day 

Comment: Good to hear that. could you accept my answer?